# Why do I get these warnings from Zend Studio?

Tags: php, warnings, zend-studio

There are a few class names that make Zend Studio give me a warning like the following wherever I use them:

```
Description                        Type
Class 'Column' not found           DLTK Problem
```

However, just like for all my other classes, the classes with those names are in files in my classes folder. Any ideas why this is happening and how to avoid it?

I'm on Windows, and my Zend Studio version is 9.0.4

Comment: Probably because Column is part of the Zend API and it would override the class methods for columns()

Comment: Probably... I refactored to avoid those names and the warnings are gone.

Comment: @DiegoSaa You should maybe try the Zend Forums.  "DLTK Problem" sounds more like an actual Zend Studio bug..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As toxicate20 noticed, the name 'Column' is part of the Zend API, so the warnings were gone after I changed the name of the class. 'Column' is probably not a good name for a class anyway...